# Transform pixel-coordinates from input image to pixel coordinates in output image

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, pixel

How can I transform pixel-coordinates from input image to pixel coordinates in georeferenced output image?

I want to georeference images (frames of a video) with GDAL and GCPs. But besides the georeferenced image I also need the pixel coordinates of the GCPs in the output image (North-up GeoTIFF) without measuring them again. I tried with GetGeoTransform() but i can not see a way to calculate the resulting pixel coordinates of the GCPs in the output image (which is georeferenced and therefore rotated and enlarged) with the [given values](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).

I am pretty new to GDAL and somewhat lost in the documentation. Further my english is not too good and I might google with the wrong words. But maybe some of you understand my question and know some handy methods.